# NotifyService.Java class is not getting invoked at all

Tags: java, android

Starting from MedicineInfoActivity.java :- onCreate function, I have called the `scheduleClient.doBindService();`.

MedicineInfoActivity.java onPostExecute function I have called the `scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);`.

When I run my code, all the java files are getting executed (verified with break points). However the NotifyService.Java class is not executed.

I declare the service class files in Manifest also:

Please check and let me know.

```
public class MedicineInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv_title;
EditText et_startdate,et_enddate, et_medicine_name, et_medicine_dosage, et_manufacturing, et_dosage, et_interval, et_time, et_comment;
CheckBox cb;
Calendar myCalendar;
Spinner spinner;
TextInputLayout TIL5;
int dic;
//EditText et_Duration;
String id;
DatePickerDialog start, end;
Button bt;
ProgressBar progressBar;
public static String startDatebrd, Timebrd;
private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medicine_info);
    scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(this);
    scheduleClient.doBindService();
    initialiseFields();

    //boolean alarm = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, new Intent("ALARM"),PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

    dic = 0;
    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

    et_startdate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date()));
    et_enddate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24)));

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=21){
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    Typeface MLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ML.ttf");
    Typeface MMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MM.ttf");
    Typeface MRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MR.ttf");

    tv_title.setTypeface(MRegular);

    /*if (alarm){
        Intent itAlarm = new Intent("ALARM");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,itAlarm,0);
        myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        myCalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarme.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),6000,pendingIntent);
    }*/

    String[] UNITS = new String[] {"Units", "Pieces", "MG", "µG", "G", "Drops", "ML", "Teaspoon", "Tablespoon", "Drop Injection", "Injection", "Tube", "Package"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, UNITS);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
            //et_Duration.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            if (dic == 0){
                updateStart(myCalendar);
            }else if (dic == 1){
                updateEnd(myCalendar);
            }
        }
    };
    et_enddate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dic = 1;
            new DatePickerDialog(MedicineInfoActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1).show();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
        }
    });
    et_startdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dic = 0;
            new DatePickerDialog(MedicineInfoActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
        }
    });

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AddInfo().execute();
        }
    });

}

private void updateStart(Calendar calendar) {
    String myFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    et_startdate.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    startDatebrd = et_startdate.getText().toString();
    //checkDat(et_startdate.getText().toString());
}

private void updateEnd(Calendar calendar) {
    String myFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    et_enddate.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    //checkDat(et_enddate.getText().toString());
}

private void initialiseFields() {
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    TIL5 = findViewById(R.id.til5);
    bt = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    et_medicine_dosage = findViewById(R.id.et_medicine_dosage);
    et_medicine_name = findViewById(R.id.et_medicine_name);
    et_manufacturing = findViewById(R.id.et_manufacturing);
    et_enddate = findViewById(R.id.et_medicine_end_date);
    //et_interval = findViewById(R.id.et_interval);
    et_dosage = findViewById(R.id.et_dosage);
    tv_title = findViewById(R.id.tv_medicineinfo_title);
    et_startdate = findViewById(R.id.et_medicine_start_date);
    et_time = findViewById(R.id.et_time);
    et_comment = findViewById(R.id.et_comment);
    cb = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
}

class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    StringBuffer sb;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String course = et_medicine_name.getText().toString();
        String medication = et_medicine_dosage.getText().toString();
        String manfacturing = et_manufacturing.getText().toString();
        String dosage = et_dosage.getText().toString();
        String quantity = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String start_date = et_startdate.getText().toString();
        String end_date = et_enddate.getText().toString();
        //String interval = et_interval.getText().toString();
        String time = et_time.getText().toString();
        String comment = et_comment.getText().toString();
        Boolean notification = cb.isChecked();

        /*List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","mayi@you.com"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("course", course));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medication", medication));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("manfacturing", manfacturing));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dosage", dosage));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", quantity));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", start_date));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("end", end_date));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("interval", interval));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comment));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notification",notification));*/

        try {
            String link = "https://medrive.000webhostapp.com/meetinfo.php?email=" + URLEncoder.encode(id,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&course=" + URLEncoder.encode(course, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&medication=" + URLEncoder.encode(medication,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
                    + "&manfacturing=" + URLEncoder.encode(manfacturing,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&dosage=" + URLEncoder.encode(dosage, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&quantity=" + URLEncoder.encode(quantity,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&start=" + URLEncoder.encode(start_date,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&end=" + URLEncoder.encode(end_date,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
                    + "&time=" + URLEncoder.encode(time,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&comment=" + URLEncoder.encode(comment,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&notification=" + URLEncoder.encode(notification.toString(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            in.close();
            //Toast.makeText(MedicineInfoActivity.this,sb.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return sb.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Boolean not = cb.isChecked();
        if (not == true){
            int Sday =  07;
            int Smonth = 02;
            int Syear = 2020;
            /*int Shour = 14;
            int Sminute = 33;
            int Ssecond = 0;*/

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Syear,Smonth,Sday);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 14);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        et_comment.setText("");
        et_medicine_name.setText("");
        et_medicine_dosage.setText("");
        et_manufacturing.setText("");
        et_dosage.setText("");
        et_startdate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date()));
        et_enddate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24)));
        //et_interval.setText("");
        et_time.setText("");
        et_medicine_name.requestFocus();
        cb.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(MedicineInfoActivity.this,sb.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}


public class ScheduleClient {
private ScheduleService mBoundService;
private Context mContext;
private boolean mIsBound;

public ScheduleClient(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with our service
    mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, ScheduleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with our service has been established,
        // giving us the service object we can use to interact with our service.
        mBoundService = ((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mBoundService = null;
    }
};

public void setAlarmForNotification(Calendar c){
    mBoundService.setAlarm(c);
}

public void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        // Detach our existing connection.
        mContext.unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
}


public class ScheduleService extends Service {

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    ScheduleService getService() {
        return ScheduleService.this;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

public void setAlarm(Calendar c) {
    // This starts a new thread to set the alarm
    // You want to push off your tasks onto a new thread to free up the UI to carry on responding
    new AlarmTask(this, c).run();
}

}


public class AlarmTask implements Runnable{

// The date selected for the alarm
private final Calendar date;
// The android system alarm manager
private final AlarmManager am;
// Your context to retrieve the alarm manager from
private final Context context;

public AlarmTask(Context context, Calendar date) {
    this.context = context;
    this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // Request to start are service when the alarm date is upon us
    // We don't start an activity as we just want to pop up a notification into the system bar not a full activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Sets an alarm - note this alarm will be lost if the phone is turned off and on again
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
}


public class NotifyService extends Service {

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    NotifyService getService() {
        return NotifyService.this;
    }
}

// Unique id to identify the notification.
private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
// Name of an intent extra we can use to identify if this service was started to create a notification
public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.blundell.tut.service.INTENT_NOTIFY";
// The system notification manager
private NotificationManager mNM;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate(ayush)");
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

    // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false)) {
        showNotification();
    }

    // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

// This is the object that receives interactions from clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

/**
 * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
 */
private void showNotification() {
    //Log.d("XXX", "show notif");
    // This is the 'title' of the notification
    CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";
    // This is the icon to use on the notification
    int icon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
    // This is the scrolling text of the notification
    CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us Sanjeet.";
    // What time to show on the notification
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /*if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("123", "TUT_CHANNEL", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("Tutorial channel");
        mNM.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }*/
    Notification notification = null;

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text);
    notification = builder.build();

    /*Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "123")
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setWhen(time)
            // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .build();*/

    // Clear the notification when it is pressed
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Send the notification to the system.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

    // Stop the service when we are finished
    stopSelf();
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think this is a lot more than minimal.